# How do I match a website stored on my computer as a file in Tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, match, tampermonkey

I have a Tampermonkey script, and I would like to match all URLs linking to
https://defly.io, so I just matched like so:

```
// @match        https://defly.io/*
```

It works just fine to include all links with defly.io at start, but I play also with an edited version that I installed on my computer, like this:

```
file:///C:/Users/----/OneDrive/Desktop/Stuff/Stuff/Untitled-1.html
```

How would I be able to @match the file as well as the normal site (defly.io)? By the way, the file is using an iframe to defly.io, so another valid solution (if possible) would be to somehow just match all iframes that link to defly.io.